# How to randomly generate a mathematical expression objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have no idea how to do this. I know how to generate a random number using `arc4_random` but I am trying to figure out how to randomly generate a `'+'` (plus) or `'-'` (minus) sign in Objective-C.
Please if anyone knows, help me out!

Comment: Probably can generate a random integer for a switch statement or a bunch of if-then-else statements

Comment: Maybe `char sign = arc4_random_uniform(1000) < 500 ? '+'  :  '-';`

Comment: The actual name is `arc4random()` and `arc4random_uniform()`, see: [Man Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html). It better and clearer to use `arc4random_uniform()` instead of `arc4random() % N`, this eliminates any modulo bias,

Answer (score 1):

If you need to generate one of `N` operators, use `arc4random_uniform(N)` and a `switch`, like this:

```
char op;
switch(arc4random_uniform(4)) {
    case 0: op = '+'; break;
    case 1: op = '-'; break;
    case 2: op = '*'; break;
    case 3: op = '/'; break;
}
```